# Handshake failed when using builtin TLS package

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2, lets-encrypt, caddy

I am having a problem/misunderstanding with SSL-TLS. My situation is the next: I have 2 backends application developed in Golang, they should communicate ech other over HTTPS, http is not allowed. Every application is running on a separate server.

Currently I am using Caddy as HTTP server and to make proxy redirections, also with it I get the SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt. Now, when I try to communicate from the ApplicationA to the ApplicationB I cannot connect, I checked the logs of the ApplicationB and this is the error:

```
Handshake failed when using builtin TLS package: no cipher suite supported by both client and server
```

I also read that this error is common when using LetsEncrypt certificates, is it true? some people recommends to buy a certificate instead, in that case, where is the problem? with the ApplicationA, ApplicationB, or boths?
I am not skilled in TLS area so looking for help.

I am using Go 1.8

Comment: The signer certainly has no impact on the available cipher suites, so insofar that the error message is accurate, whether you use Let's Encrypt or another CA plays no role.

Comment: @fuglede ok, what would be the cause of the error? I found it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/neu_jKq9pYk

Comment: Caddy allows only a very limited set of cipher suites by default, but they can be modified (https://caddyserver.com/docs/tls). Which library are you using for the client?

Comment: @fuglede I am using github.com/ory-am/hydra/sdk ...The client app, indeed is this one https://github.com/ory/hydra-consent-app-go

Comment: That looks like it's a webserver itself; can you provide the code you use to communicate with the Caddy instance, as well as the output of `openssl s_client -connect caddy-host:443` (to get an idea of which ciphers it wants to use)?